# ¿Como puedo implementar esta fraccion de codigo en mi solucion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

hola amigos estoy haciendo una pagina web y pues me funciona tranquilamente todo lo que quiero que haga, pero existe un funcion visual que quiero darle como estilo, es la parte visual del Reload, solamente con bootstrap aqui les muestro mi codigo html

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <strong id="Cargando_Texto">Procesando...</strong>
  <div id="Cargando" class="spinner-border ml-auto" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></div>
</div>
```

lo que deseo es que aparezca este div cuando se mande a cualquiera tarea de la pagina y aparezca mientras se esta esperando, para que el usuario pueda saber que algo esta sucediendo.
No cuento con la funcion jquery o javasript para poder dar ese dinamismos a mi pagina html.

Comment: Ponle un id a ese div por ejemplo "loading" y mantén el div oculto. Cuando empieces a realizar una acción que pueda tardar (lo más común serán llamadas AJAX) haz $("#loading").show(). Una vez acabada la acción ya sea porque haya sido éxito o fracaso, acuérdate de hacer $("#loading").hide() para ocultar el div.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda-... me funciono